# See indices implicitly created for foreign key constaints in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb, index, foreign-key

When I add a foreign key constraint to my table, `SHOW INDEX` doesn't show any new indices, but the overall space used by the indices in that table increases. Apparently, the index for the field I put a constraint on does get created implicitly, but MySQL doesn't want me to tell about its existence. Is there a way to see those implicit indices anyway?

The table type is InnoDB.

Comment: Is one or more of the columns of the foreign key included in another index?

Comment: Yes, it's a part of another composite index. I'm not sure whether MySQL is just relying on that index, or creating a new one. The fact that the constraint creation operation takes quite a while and the table file gets bigger is sort of indicative that some new index might be created, but I don't quite know how to be certain here.